# Como puedo utilizar un pincel y elegir un color para pintar en c# windowsform

Tags: c#, windows-forms

soy nuevo en esto de programacion c# y estoy intentando hacer un pequeño programa que me permita elegir un color y poder pintar.

aquí un ejemplo de lo que digo y necesito. cuando elija el color rojo que me permita dibujar encima de esta imagen, al igual que los demás colores.

[image: poder elegir color y pintar estilo paint.]

Answer (score -1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Color color;
        List<List<Point>> Lineas;
        List<Pen> pincel;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            color = Color.Transparent;
            Lineas = new List<List<Point>>();
            pincel = new List<Pen>();
        }

        private void panel4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel p = (Panel)(sender);
            color = p.BackColor;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MouseButtons==MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Lineas.Last().Add(e.Location);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Lineas.Add(new List<Point>());
            pincel.Add(new Pen(color,2));

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int p = 0;
            foreach(var lineset in Lineas)
            {
                if (lineset.Count>1)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pincel[p], lineset.ToArray());
                    p++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Debes de tener en cuenta que los paneles deben de tener el mismo evento o si no sino lo haces por separado.

Comment: Gracias, ya pude resolver.